# DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Никак не могу удалить VM VirtualBox с Убунту. Постоянно выдает одно и то же.
Не эксперт в Линухе, помогите, кто как сможет?
Вот что выдает в коммандной строке.

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
[sudo] password for arthur: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 libkeybinder-3.0-0
  linux-headers-5.4.0-37 linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 302 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.10-138449~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.1 (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-6.1 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

При попытке удалить через Ubuntu Software выдает следующее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/380701/416190

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо тебе, наконец-то!

Answer (score 1):

> `debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable`

[файл `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` заблокирован другим процессом](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingInstallationIssues#DbDriver_.22config.22_is_locked).

возможно, вы сами запустили параллельную установку/удаление/обновление каких-то пакетов. или выполняется автоматическое фоновое обновление ([unattended-upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_ubuntu_server/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/automatic_updates)).

тогда просто дождитесь завершения блокирующего процесса и повторите попытку.

узнать, какой процесс блокирует файл можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

если процесс продолжает «висеть», можно добавить опции `-k` («убить» блокирующий процесс) и `-i` (интерактивное подтверждение):

```
$ sudo fuser -vki /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

и утвердительно ответить на вопрос «`kill process номер ? (y/N)`»