# Неудовлетворенные зависимости в Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, зависимости

Не устанавливаются пакеты через терминал, на любую попытку вываливается ошибка:

```
stepan@stepan-X505BA:~$ sudo apt install fpc
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет fpc самой новой версии (3.0.4+dfsg-18ubuntu2).
Вы можете запустить «apt --fix-broken install» для исправления этих ошибок.
Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libgcc1:i386 : Зависит: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) но он не будет установлен
 libgcrypt20:i386 : Зависит: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) но он не будет установлен
 libgpg-error0:i386 : Зависит: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) но он не будет установлен
 liblz4-1:i386 : Зависит: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) но он не будет установлен
 liblzma5:i386 : Зависит: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) но он не будет установлен
 E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не 
    указывая имени пакета (или указав решение).
```

Команда

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

от лица суперпользователя также выдает ошибку

```
root@stepan-X505BA:~# apt --fix-broken install
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Исправление зависимостей… Готово
Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты:
  libc6:i386
Предлагаемые пакеты:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  libc6:i386
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 32 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 5 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/2 550 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 10,8 MB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] Д
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 198003 файла и каталога.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb …
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Подскажите, как лечить? Ответ на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148853/dbdriver-config-var-cache-debconf-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process) не дает эффекта

Comment: попробуйте выполнить эти команды(можете скопировать вместе с точкой с запятой и вставить в терминал: sudo apt clean; sudo apt autoremove; sudo apt update; sudo apt -f install;

Comment: Было много прелюдий, но в конце все равно:

При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: с добавлением архитектур игрались?

Comment: Нет, и не знаю, что это значит. Сможете объяснить, пожалуйста?